# jQuery and jQueryMobile File Size Confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, filesize

I would like to use jQuery and jQueryMobile on an embedded web server. However, my storage space is very limited for storing web resources (images, .js, .html, etc) - so, if the jQuery files are too large, I will need to write my own JS to do the things I want to do (I have ~200kb of storage space).

So when I was watching [Marc Graganski give a presentation on jQueryMobile](http://vimeo.com/46801419), I was stoked to see that jQuery is 29kb and jQueryMobile is ~18kb (You can see this at around 14:14 in the presentation).

Jumping right in, I [downloaded jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and quickly noticed that the jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js file is 193KB and the jquery-1.11.0.min.js file is ~98KB. These file sizes are nowhere close to the 29kb and ~18kb that Marc spoke of and push my storage limit to where I will not be able to make use of these API's.

What am I missing here? Are there some other JQ/JQM files that are under the ~30KB file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery CDN http://code.jquery.com you don't have to host it. Given file sizes are after gzip.

Comment: CDN is not an option as the client may not have an Internet connection. But, ah! @gzip. Now I'll need to determine if my embedded server supports it. Thanks.